# Prevent ajax call if input is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What is the correct way of preventing an ajax call if someone where to enter a blank space in an input field?

The code I am trying to do would look something like this (obviously this does not work)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#insert_btn', function() {
    if ($("#first_name").val().length > 0)) {

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'add.php',
      datatype: "json",
      data: {
        first_name: $("#first_name").val(),
        last_name: $("#last_name").val(),
        position: $("#position").val(),
        date: $("#date").val(),
        updated: $("#updated").val(),
      },
      success: function(result) {
        if (result == ADD_OK) {
          alert('OK')

        } else {
          alert('wrong');
        }
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: You can validate `#first_name` after trimming the value, or use regexes to test if that's the input you expect, then proceed with ajax.

Comment: how about using `$("#first_name").val() != ""` instead of checking length

Comment: yeah I originally had something similar like that.

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar the question is about to check for blank spaces not blank strings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery already you can go for something like the code below where I've added the use of [jQuery.trim](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) before checking for the length

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('click', '#insert_btn', function () {

    // Utilizing https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/
    var first_name = $.trim($("#first_name").val());

    if (first_name.length > 0) {

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add.php',
        datatype: "json",
        data: {
          first_name: $("#first_name").val(),
          last_name: $("#last_name").val(),
          position: $("#position").val(),
          date: $("#date").val(),
          updated: $("#updated").val(),
        },
        success: function (result) {
          if (result == ADD_OK) {
            alert('OK')

          } else {
            alert('wrong');
          }
        }
      })
    }
  });
});
```

### jQuery Trim:

```
jQuery.trim(' ') // returns ""
jQuery.trim('     ') // returns ""
jQuery.trim(' this is my search text      ') // returns "this is my search text"
```

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar because that does not work if someone enters blanks. Did you even read his question?

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar The question is to get rid of calls that directly enter a blank space eg: `" "` not "nothing".

Comment: I copied the code and my insert button does not seem to work now. https://databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: I think there may be a syntax error according to my console near the end   }); 
}); 
</script>

Comment: Seems like a missing } -> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) at the end

Comment: great thanks guys! marked as answer. do you by chance know why the alert("add successful") does not trigger? I hear it may have to do something with location.reload() as it cant work at same time as alert?

Comment: As far as I know alert tries to freeze the screen, depending on your call of the reload the reload might be first and the alert won't be executed because you refreshed the site and therefore the code is no longer at that "success" state but on a reseted state